# get route from google maps and points on the map each 2 km

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know GPS coordinates my start and end point. Now I would like to get driving route for this journey. And then get GPS coordinates of every 2nd km on this route. How can I do this with php/javascript?

Thanks

Code added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>creation of markers along a route - jsFiddle demo by doktormolle</title>
  <!--
  < script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script >

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  -->



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

  /** 
    * creates markers along a google.maps.DirectionsRoute
    *     
    * @param route object google.maps.DirectionsRoute
    * @param dist  int    interval for milestones in meters
    * @param opts  object google.maps.MarkerOptions  
    * @return array Array populated with created google.maps.Marker-objects
    **/     

  function gMilestone(route,dist,opts)
  {

    var markers=[],
        geo=google.maps.geometry.spherical,
        path=route.overview_path,
        point=path[0],
        distance=0,
        leg,
        overflow,
        pos;

      for(var p=1;p<path.length;++p)
      { 
        leg=Math.round(geo.computeDistanceBetween(point,path[p]));
        d1=distance+0
        distance+=leg;        
        overflow=dist-(d1%dist);

        if(distance>=dist && leg>=overflow)
        {
          if(overflow && leg>=overflow)
          { 
            pos=geo.computeOffset(point,overflow,geo.computeHeading(point,path[p]));
            opts.position=pos;
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
            distance-=dist;
          }

          while(distance>=dist)
          { 
            pos=geo.computeOffset(point,dist+overflow,geo.computeHeading(point,path[p]));
            opts.position=pos;
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
            distance-=dist;
          }
        }
        point=path[p]
      }


    document.getElementById("pMsg").innerHTML = markers;
    //alert(markers);
    return markers;    

  }  
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body onload="ginit()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:400px;"></div>
<ul></ul>
<p id="pMsg"></p>
<script>
  var directions={};


  function ginit() 
  {
    var opts = {
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013)
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), opts);


    var routes=[
                { label:'Erkner',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4244119, 13.749783200000024), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'},draggable:true}
                },
                /*{ label:'Potsdam',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3941887, 13.072690999999963), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'},draggable:true}
                },
                { label:'Bernau',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.683483, 13.587553999999955), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'},draggable:true}
                }*/
               ];
    var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var dists=[5000,3000,1000];
    var selects=document.createElement('select');
    list=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    for(var d=0;d<dists.length;++d)
    {
      selects.options[selects.options.length]=new Option(dists[d],dists[d],d==0,d==0);
    }

    for(var r=0;r<routes.length;++r)
    {
      bounds.extend(routes[r].request.destination);
      routes[r].rendering.routeId='r'+r+new Date().getTime();
      routes[r].rendering.dist=dists[0];
      var select=selects.cloneNode(true);
          select.setAttribute('name',routes[r].rendering.routeId);
          select.onchange=function(){directions[this.name].renderer.dist=this.value;setMarkers(this.name)};
      list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
      list.lastChild.appendChild(select);
      list.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(routes[r].label));

      requestRoute(routes[r],map);
    } 
    map.fitBounds(bounds) ;
  }


  function setMarkers(ID)
  {
    var direction=directions[ID],
        renderer=direction.renderer,
        dist=renderer.dist,
        marker=renderer.marker,
        map=renderer.getMap(),
        dirs=direction.renderer.getDirections();
        marker.map=map;

    for(var k in direction.sets)
    {

       var set=directions[ID].sets[k];
           set.visible=!!(k===dist);

       for(var m=0;m<set.length;++m)
       {

          set[m].setMap((set.visible)?map:null);
       } 
    }
    if(!direction.sets[dist])
    {
      if(dirs.routes.length)
      {
        var route=dirs.routes[0];
        var az=0;
        for(var i=0;i<route.legs.length;++i)
        {
          if(route.legs[i].distance)
          {
            az+=route.legs[i].distance.value;
          }

        }
       dist=Math.max(dist,Math.round(az/100));
       direction.sets[dist]=gMilestone(route,dist,marker);

      }
    }
  }

  function requestRoute(route,map) 
  {
    if(!window.gDirSVC)
    {
      window.gDirSVC = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    }

    var renderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
     var renderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
        renderer.setMap(map);
        renderer.setOptions({preserveViewport:true})


    google.maps.event.addListener(renderer, 'directions_changed', function() {

          if(directions[this.routeId])
          {
           //remove markers
            for(var k in directions[this.routeId].sets)
            {              
                for(var m=0;m<directions[this.routeId].sets[k].length;++m)
                {
                  directions[this.routeId].sets[k][m].setMap(null);
                }
            }
          }

          directions[this.routeId]={renderer:this,sets:{}};
          setMarkers(this.routeId);

    });

    window.gDirSVC.route(route.request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        renderer.setDirections(response);
    }
    });
  }

</script>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You can do it with the the Google Maps Javascript API, [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polyline_example_kmmarkers_0.html), no need for PHP.

Comment: possibly related question [Add Markers Along a Route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594598/add-markers-along-a-route)

Comment: P.S. how can I get GPS coordinates from markers? And how can I set distance 2km between markers in example?

Comment: What do you mean by get GPS coordinates from markers?  have you looked at the [Google Maps Javascript API v3 documentation on Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)? What does your code look like?

Comment: I added my code. By GPS marker coordinates  I mean coordinates of blue markes on my route.

Answer (score 3):

My answer for other people: Use code in comments and console.log(markers) - there are GPS coordinates - see in code + see interval for milestones in meters. I did not use php but javascript.

[working fiddle with code below](http://jsfiddle.net/kujkeh1f/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>creation of markers along a route - jsFiddle demo by doktormolle</title>
  <!--
  < script type='text/javascript' src='/js/lib/dummy.js'></script >

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  -->



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 

  /** 
    * creates markers along a google.maps.DirectionsRoute
    *     
    * @param route object google.maps.DirectionsRoute
    * @param dist  int    interval for milestones in meters
    * @param opts  object google.maps.MarkerOptions  
    * @return array Array populated with created google.maps.Marker-objects
    **/     

  function gMilestone(route,dist,opts)
  {

    var markers=[],
        geo=google.maps.geometry.spherical,
        path=route.overview_path,
        point=path[0],
        distance=0,
        leg,
        overflow,
        pos;

      for(var p=1;p<path.length;++p)
      { 
        leg=Math.round(geo.computeDistanceBetween(point,path[p]));
        d1=distance+0
        distance+=leg;        
        overflow=dist-(d1%dist);

        if(distance>=dist && leg>=overflow)
        {
          if(overflow && leg>=overflow)
          { 
            pos=geo.computeOffset(point,overflow,geo.computeHeading(point,path[p]));
            opts.position=pos;
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
            distance-=dist;
          }

          while(distance>=dist)
          { 
            pos=geo.computeOffset(point,dist+overflow,geo.computeHeading(point,path[p]));
            opts.position=pos;
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker(opts));
            distance-=dist;
          }
        }
        point=path[p]
      }


    document.getElementById("pMsg").innerHTML = markers;
    console.log(markers); //alert(markers);

    for (var key in markers) {
       var obj = markers[key];
       console.log(obj);
       console.log(obj['position']['k']);
       /*
       for (var prop in obj) {
          // important check that this is objects own property 
          // not from prototype prop inherited
          if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            alert(prop + " = " + obj[prop]);
          }
       }*/
    }

    return markers;    

  }  
//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body onload="ginit()">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:400px;"></div>
<ul></ul>
<p id="pMsg"></p>
<script>
  var directions={};


  function ginit() 
  {
    var opts = {
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013)
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), opts);


    var routes=[
                { label:'Erkner',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.4244119, 13.749783200000024), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'},draggable:true}
                },
                /*{ label:'Potsdam',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3941887, 13.072690999999963), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'},draggable:true}
                },
                { label:'Bernau',
                  request:{
                    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(52.524268, 13.406290000000013), 
                    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(52.683483, 13.587553999999955), 
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING},
                  rendering:{marker:{icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png'},draggable:true}
                }*/
               ];
    var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var dists=[10000,5000,3000,1000];
    var selects=document.createElement('select');
    list=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    for(var d=0;d<dists.length;++d)
    {
      selects.options[selects.options.length]=new Option(dists[d],dists[d],d==0,d==0);
    }

    for(var r=0;r<routes.length;++r)
    {
      bounds.extend(routes[r].request.destination);
      routes[r].rendering.routeId='r'+r+new Date().getTime();
      routes[r].rendering.dist=dists[0];
      var select=selects.cloneNode(true);
          select.setAttribute('name',routes[r].rendering.routeId);
          select.onchange=function(){directions[this.name].renderer.dist=this.value;setMarkers(this.name)};
      list.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));
      list.lastChild.appendChild(select);
      list.lastChild.appendChild(document.createTextNode(routes[r].label));

      requestRoute(routes[r],map);
    } 
    map.fitBounds(bounds) ;
  }


  function setMarkers(ID)
  {
    var direction=directions[ID],
        renderer=direction.renderer,
        dist=renderer.dist,
        marker=renderer.marker,
        map=renderer.getMap(),
        dirs=direction.renderer.getDirections();
        marker.map=map;

    for(var k in direction.sets)
    {

       var set=directions[ID].sets[k];
           set.visible=!!(k===dist);

       for(var m=0;m<set.length;++m)
       {

          set[m].setMap((set.visible)?map:null);
       } 
    }
    if(!direction.sets[dist])
    {
      if(dirs.routes.length)
      {
        var route=dirs.routes[0];
        var az=0;
        for(var i=0;i<route.legs.length;++i)
        {
          if(route.legs[i].distance)
          {
            az+=route.legs[i].distance.value;
          }

        }
       dist=Math.max(dist,Math.round(az/100));
       direction.sets[dist]=gMilestone(route,dist,marker);

      }
    }
  }

  function requestRoute(route,map) 
  {
    if(!window.gDirSVC)
    {
      window.gDirSVC = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    }

    var renderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
     var renderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(route.rendering);
        renderer.setMap(map);
        renderer.setOptions({preserveViewport:true})


    google.maps.event.addListener(renderer, 'directions_changed', function() {

          if(directions[this.routeId])
          {
           //remove markers
            for(var k in directions[this.routeId].sets)
            {              
                for(var m=0;m<directions[this.routeId].sets[k].length;++m)
                {
                  directions[this.routeId].sets[k][m].setMap(null);
                }
            }
          }

          directions[this.routeId]={renderer:this,sets:{}};
          setMarkers(this.routeId);

    });

    window.gDirSVC.route(route.request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        renderer.setDirections(response);
    }
    });
  }

</script>


</body>


</html>
```