# How to get nth kilometer of my route Google maps API v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I have app that build route between 2 points. I need to get point on map depending from distance.

For example ,if 1000 km is total distance, and I enter 800km,  then app should show point(marker) of 800th km on the map

Comment: who knows?
i dont have ideas -_-

Comment: I remember there were at least 2 posts here regarding to this... I think the answer used the polyline in a really smart way. Both are with javascript API v3 but the same logic should apply.... if anyone can find that post that would be great

Comment: oh,
i will find,
hope

Comment: oh I think it is one of them, [get route from google maps and points on the map each 2 km](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389058/get-route-from-google-maps-and-points-on-the-map-each-2-km)