# Getting individual coordinates from OSMDroid routing, to use in finding elevations on trip

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I am trying to create a hill finder application

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs0FH.jpg)

The user enters a starting location, and an end location. With the end goal of displaying a chart with the elevations of the road in the trip

Currently, I have managed to get it to create a route between point A and point B. I needed to use routing, since in my use case, the user has to stay on the road and can't just draw a straight line

code so far:

```
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(requireContext(), "MY_USER_AGENT");
ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<>();
waypoints.add(startPoint);
GeoPoint endPoint = new GeoPoint(48.069842, -1.712637);
waypoints.add(endPoint);
Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);
Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
map.invalidate();
Drawable nodeIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_baseline_location_on_24);
for (int i=0; i<road.mNodes.size(); i++){
    RoadNode node = road.mNodes.get(i);
    Marker nodeMarker = new Marker(map);
    nodeMarker.setPosition(node.mLocation);
    nodeMarker.setIcon(nodeIcon);
    nodeMarker.setTitle("Step "+i);
    map.getOverlays().add(nodeMarker);
}
```

Took this from the guide on the osmdroid bonus pack github page

I already have a system in place to load elevations from coordinates elsewhere in the app. I just need to get the coordinates from the route. At least every 10 feet or so, **not just the intersections**

I'm hoping this is possible with osmdroid, especially since this has been done with google's apis. However, that code was not open, and I don't want to be charged per usage

My best guess was something with projection(), but I barely know how to use it

NOTE: I won't be using this for long distances, probably at most a mile is what the user would need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think omsdroid can do this out of the box. However you can solve this:

roadOverlay.getPoints() will give you ArrayList containing the "turning" points. You can then apply some math to calculate what you need. I would do it like this:

1. Calculate distance in feet between two turning points. [Calculate distance between 2 GPS coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365826/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-coordinates)
2. Divide the distance by 10 feet (as mentioned in your post) and subtract 1. You will get the number of points between the 2 turning points.
3. Apply some more math to get lat and lng of each of the points on the road. You can inspire here. [How to calculate the points between two given points and given distance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249739/how-to-calculate-the-points-between-two-given-points-and-given-distance) or [Calculate point between two coordinates based on a percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907276/calculate-point-between-two-coordinates-based-on-a-percentage)
4. You can now use the elevation API for the points. Do not forget to get the elevation of the turning points, too.
5. Get the next 2 turning points and repeat. :-)